# Django Admin Logo not Loading

Tags: css, django

I have created a new file base_site.html as per the books and in it i put this code:

```
{% extends "admin/base.html" %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{% block title %}{{ title }} | {{ site_title|default:_('ADP site admin') }}{% endblock%}
{% block branding %}
<h1 id="site-name">
    <a href="{% url 'admin:index' %}">My site 
        <img src="{% static '/parcare/images/logo.png' %}" height="40px" />
    </a>

</h1>
{% endblock %}
 {% block nav-global %}{% endblock %}
```

This is from settings.py

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

And this is my static folder situation
[image]

What am I doing wrong here?

[image]

Comment: Did you run `python manage.py collectstatics` ? How are you serving your static files ... apache wsgi? gnuicorn? You'll have to ensure your web server knows about the location of your static files.

Comment: yes. currently i am still on development so i am working on my laptop.

Comment: Is the file `logo.png` actually where it should be?

Comment: yes. is where it should be. as per the books...

Answer (score 0):

it worked with this ++> i added staticdirs

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'


STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
```